# Various Python Scripts Occasionally Crashing: "XXX Ambiguity!"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a system which is constantly running various python scripts as workers -- they are restarted upon exiting, resulting in each being run around several hundred times per day. All is well, except that every couple of days one of them will randomly crash with the following error

```
XXX ambiguity!\nXXX ambiguity!\nXXX ambiguity!\nXXX ambiguity!\n...
XXX ambiguity!\nXXX ambiguity!\nXXX ambiguity!\nXXX ambiguity!\n...
Error processing line 1 of /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope.interface-3.6.1-nspkg.pth:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py\", line 157, in addpackage
      exec line
    File \"<string>\", line 1
    import sys,types,os; p = os.path.join(sys._getframe(1).f_locals['sitedir'], *('zope',)); ie = os.path.exists(os.path.join(p,'__init__.py')); m = not ie and sys.modules.setdefault('zope',types.ModuleType('zope')); mp = (m or []) and m.__dict__.setdefault('__path__',[]); (p not in mp) and mp.append(p)
        SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
        Remainder of file ignored
XXX ambiguity!\nXXX ambiguity!\nXXX ambiguity!\nXXX ambiguity!\n...
MemoryError
```

Sorry if I munged the trace, my logging does ugly things to it. Also, note that I've truncated the `XXX` lines: `XXX ambiguity!\n` is actually repeated perhaps a hundred times.

I do NOT use `zope.interface` anywhere in my own code: it was installed as a dependency for tornado, more specifically `tornado.twisted`, which I also don't use. Though, I tend to think the problem is with python (or how I use it to execute my scripts) and the stack pointing the finger at `zope.interface` is just a symptom.

The scripts themselves are run using `/usr/bin/nice`, and typically take the form of

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sharedlib import queue
import time
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def main():
    for item in queue.rest:  # queue.rest yields from an immutable source
        logger.info("An item in the queue: %s", item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    time.sleep(600)  # Used for throttling the rate of script execution
```

Thanks in advance -- this has been driving me up the wall.

Comment: maybe first find where the error comes from `grep XXX -r .`?

Comment: That code from `site.py` is trying to parse a PTH file.  Look at all the PTH files in your Python site-packages directory.  One of them is trying to do something very hairy and weird.

Comment: @JakubM. There's nothing matching that in my own code, or site-packages|dist-packages. I'll look a bit deeper into python itself in a bit after following up with the PTH files. Thanks!

Comment: Googling a bit, it looks like that code in the PTH file is actually part of how Zope sets itself up.  To get much further on this problem you really need to show code of these workers that you're using, and track down where the XXX message is coming from.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks for the help, a couple things:
a) I have two .pth files: `setuptools.pth`, and `zope.interface-3.6.1-nspkg.pth` -- both appear to be fine
b) Sorry, but I can't share my code: it's for work. However, there are about twenty separate scripts, each doing very different things, and each appears to be as likely as failing with ~0.01% chance. I honestly don't think it's within the code itself, but rather how I'm running it.

Comment: @BrenBarn also, http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/33983/ indicates that the problem could be stemming from the python parser itself

Comment: There's no way we can help without seeing any of your code.  That message you linked to does indicate something in the parser, but that doesn't narrow it down much.  Is any of your code doing anything with the parser?  Are you using a custom-compiled version of Python?  Without seeing code, all anyone can do is tell you to try to debug it yourself until you can isolate which of the workers is causing the problem and when.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26698/discussion-between-jtmoulia-and-brenbarn)